# Problem on limits $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

I have the problem with the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to ∞} \frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: See also:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1526398
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2114065
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2415683
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3040278

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum):
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}} = \int_0^1\sqrt{x}dx = \frac{2}{3}.
$$