# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{-3/2}(1+\sqrt{2}+\ldots+\sqrt{n})=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2} + ... + \sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: limits, radicals

How do I find the following limit?

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2} + ... + \sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}
$$

The answer (from [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%7D%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%20%2B%20...%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7D%7Bn%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7D)) is $\frac{2}{3}$, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Is this an application of the Squeeze theorem? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Do you know about Riemann sums?

Comment: @gobucksmath Not that much. Would appreciate a nudge.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/how-closely-can-we-estimate-sum-i-0n-sqrti

Comment: Another solution would be to compare $k^{1/2}$ with $\int_{k}^{k+1} t^{1/2} dt$ to get the behaviour of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{k}$ and then you can conclude.

Comment: @HungryBlueDev, I added an equivalent expression $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-\frac{3}{2}}(1+\sqrt{2}+\ldots+\sqrt{n})$ in the title to prevent future possible duplicates because  I've seen this task in both forms. Sincerely

Comment: See also:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1172144
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1526398
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2415683
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3040278

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}} = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{2}{3}}$$
by [Riemann sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) and the integrability of $\sqrt{x}$ over $[0,1]$.

For a more elementary approach, notice that $\sqrt{k}$ is pretty close to $\frac{2}{3}\left[\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3/2}-\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3/2}\right]$ and apply creative telescoping and squeezing.

Answer (score 4):

How about Stolz-Cesaro? If $x_n \to \infty $, $y_n \to \infty $ and $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{y_{n+1}-y_n}$$ exists, then : $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{y_{n+1}-y_n}$$

Comment: Okay, that's interesting... But what will be $x_n$? I think $\sqrt{n}$? And what about $y_n$?

Comment: $x_n$ will be whole numerator of your fraction

Answer (score 4):

All the other answers are by Riemann sums, but one can also use the Stolz theorem. The limit becomes 
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}-(n-1)\sqrt{n-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}(n\sqrt{n}+(n-1)\sqrt{n-1})}{n^3+(n-1)^3}=$$ 
$$\frac{n^2+(n-1)\sqrt{n^2-n})}{n^2+n(n-1)+(n-1)^2}\to\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No I think its the other way around, like l'hospitals rule, after all, its really the discrete version. You need also that $y_n\to\infty$.

Comment: All right, my bad. The (+1) stays :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Phew, that was a close one.... I just looked it up in my notes $y_n$ also has to be increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Fill in details: $$\frac1{n\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt k=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt\frac kn\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\int_0^1\sqrt x\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Using $\;\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int_0^1f(x)\;dx,$ we get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{2} +\ldots + \sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}=\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\;dx=\frac{2}{3}.$$