# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt 1 + \sqrt 2 + \dots + \sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt 1 + \sqrt 2 + \dots + \sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt 1 + \sqrt 2 + \dots + \sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}} =\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac1{n}\sum^{n}_{k = 1} \sqrt{\dfrac k n} $$

While searching this question I found,
[Turning infinite sum into integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356472/turning-infinite-sum-into-integral).

Like in the accepted answer I first compared my series to LRAM,

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n f\left(a+\frac{b-a}n i \right)$$

I got $a = 0$, $b = 1$ and $f(x) =\sqrt{x}$ so,

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}\ dx = \dfrac2 3$$ should be the answer.

Is there any simpler method to do this sum ? I have not learnt this method to do infinite sums so I can't use it.

Comment: You haven't learned this method to do infinite sums, but have you learned about integrals and their definition? I have seen questions like this appear on the various standardized tests, and the intent is to recognize them as integrals and use an antiderivative to most quickly determine their value.

Comment: See also:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1172144
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1526398
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2114065
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3040278

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By [the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt 1 + \sqrt 2 + \dots + \sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}\\
&=&\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}-n\sqrt n}\\
&=&\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}-n\sqrt n} \dfrac{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}+n\sqrt n}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}+n\sqrt n}\\
&=&\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}[(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}+n\sqrt n]}{(n+1)^3-n^3}\\
&=&\frac23.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: +1, I hate it when people beat me  due to their fast typing speed. :P

Comment: If yours is independent, submit it anyway. Your explanation may be clearer.

Comment: @martycohen, If xpaul took stolz cesaro from me then what.... I will still submit my answer. :P

Comment: He did not take it away. This is not a zero sum game.

Answer (score 6):

picture......................................

[image]

$$ \frac{2}{3} n \sqrt n < \mbox{SUM} < \frac{2}{3} \left( \; (n+1) \sqrt {n+1}  \; - \; 1 \right)  \; < \;  \frac{2}{3} \left( \; (n+1) ( 1 +\sqrt n)  \; - \; 1 \right) =  \frac{2}{3} \left( \; n \sqrt n + n + \sqrt n  \right)   $$
$$ \frac{2}{3} n \sqrt n < \mbox{SUM} <  \frac{2}{3} \left( \; n \sqrt n + n + \sqrt n  \right)   $$

For anyone worried about the little estimate above,
$$ n + 1 < n + 2 \sqrt n + 1, $$
$$ \sqrt {n+1} \; \;  < \; \; 1 + \sqrt n. $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Learning new techniques is good:

**Method to express the infinite series as definite integral:**

$1.$ Express the given series in the form $\sum\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{r}{n})$.

$2.$ Then the limit is its sum when $n\to \infty$, i.e, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{r}{n})$

$3.$ Replace $\frac{r}{n}$ by $x$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ by $dx$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum$ by $\int$

$4.$ The upper and lower limit are limiting values of $\frac{r}{n}$ for first and last term of $r$ respectively.

> For instance: $\sum_{r=1}^n=\int\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{r}{n})=\int_0^1f(x).dx$.

Now, let's see your question:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt 1 + \sqrt 2 + \dots + \sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{r}{n}}=\int_0^1\sqrt{x}=\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: This is exactly the technique outlined by the OP (who is looking for *other* techniques). But also, based on some of your comments above -- don't let fast typing get in the way of typo-freeness :) you have 4 typos in the first two lines...

Comment: @ClementC., I posted a compete method so that OP can learn about this technique. Notice his words: *I have not learnt this method to do infinite sums so I can't use it* and then notice my words: *Learning new techniques is good*

Comment: Thanks for the answer.